# What happens if you run out of cards in Streaking Kittens

Tags: exploding-kittens, streaking-kittens

I know [this question has already been asked](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27013/running-out-of-cards-in-exploding-kittens?rq=1), but this situation is different because we use the Streaking Kitten expansion of Exploding Kittens.

Answer (score 6):

The [streaking kitten expansion](https://explodingkittens.com/how-to-play/streaking-kittens) introduces the streaking kitten card, it allows a player to keep one (and only one) kitten in her hand:

> **Streaking Kitten 1 Card**
>
> While this card is in your hand, you can also secretly hold 1
>   Exploding Kitten without exploding.
>
> But...
>
> If the Streaking Kitten leaves your hand for any reason, the Exploding
>   Kitten in your hand will explode.
>
> If another player steals or receives an Exploding Kitten from your
>   hand, they explode. They must defuse it or lose the game.
>
> If you take any action causing you to play an Exploding Kitten from
>   your hand into the Discard Pile, you explode. You must defuse it or
>   lose the game.
>
> IMPORTANT - Streaking Kittens and Exploding Kittens can not be used
>   with the 5 Card Special Combo. This means you can't use either of them
>   in your collection of 5 cards, nor can you remove either of them from
>   the Discard Pile.
>
> Why? Because it breaks the game. Don't break the game...the game loves
>   you.

If for example, there are 4 players. Using streaking kittens expansion, the deck has 4 kittens. The moment you are running out of cards, 4 kittens must have been played of which at most one is streaking at one of the players. The other 3 kittens must have been exploded eliminating 3 players. So there is only one player left who is the winner.

This can only occur if something went wrong:

- You put 3 kittens in the deck. *This expansion adds one kitten for each player.*
- A defused kitten is discarded. *Defused kittens are put back in the draw pile.*
- The player with the streaking kitten card collected more than a single kitten. *A streaking kitten card only let you keep one kitten.*
- The streaking kitten card was stolen, enabling an other player to collect a kitten, but the original kitten "forgot" to explode. *If you lose the streaking kitten card while holding a kitten, it explodes.*